# Measure to apply calculation based on column value (i.e case statement in SQL terms)

Tags: powerbi, dax

very new to DAX here. I'm trying to apply a calculation based on the value or "category" of a column.

I've got the calculation to work but it's only displaying the rows where the calculation criteria is met. What i'd like to do is say IF the value is in "CancelRT", "NoShowRT","FillRate", etc... then perform this calculation, otherwise leave the value in "newunits" be.

The following works but only returns the rows that contain the values specified:

```
Percentages = 
DIVIDE ( 
Calculate(
SUM ( MMP_Dashboards_WMH_PBI[NewUnits] ),  MMP_Dashboards_WMH_PBI[Revenue_center]="FillRate" ||MMP_Dashboards_WMH_PBI[Revenue_center]="CancelRT" ||MMP_Dashboards_WMH_PBI[Revenue_center]="NoShowRT" || MMP_Dashboards_WMH_PBI[Revenue_center]="ExamRt"
),

COUNTROWS ( VALUES ( MMP_Dashboards_WMH_PBI[Provider_Finance] ) ) 
)
```

What I'd like to see is IF Revenue_Center IN ("FilRate","CancelRt","NoshowRT",ExamRt" Then do the calculation, otherwise Just use NewUnits

I've tried playing around with the following but the syntax is definitely off:

```
Units=

IF (
    MMP_Dashboards_WMH_PBI[Revenue_center]) IN {"FillRate","CancelRt","NoShowRt","ExamRt"}

DIVIDE ( 
Calculate(
SUM ( MMP_Dashboards_WMH_PBI[NewUnits] ),
),

COUNTROWS ( VALUES ( MMP_Dashboards_WMH_PBI[Provider_Finance] ) ) 
)
)
```

Thank you all in advance for any assistance you can provide!

The Data Looks something like this:

```
Provider_Finance   Revenue_Center       NewUnits
John               Surgical             47.000
OSBORN             Testing              1.000
RAZDAN             FillRate             1.000
RAZDAN             FillRate             1.000
ANDREW             Exams                120.000
```

When grouped on the report I want to get the average for Razdan based on the revenue center being "FillRate" and taking the count of "Provider Finance" (2) and the other metrics to be left as is:

```
Provider_Finance   Revenue_Center       NewUnits
John               Surgical             47.000
OSBORN             Testing              1.000
RAZDAN             FillRate             1.000 --The average
ANDREW             Exams                120.000
```

In my first code example it returns the data set below which works, but only includes the fillrate metric as it's filtering the other non-calculated values out.

```
Provider_Finance   Revenue_Center       NewUnits
RAZDAN             FillRate             1.000 --The average
```

Comment: Please add some dummy data to your question and your desired output.

Comment: Added - Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it

```
Units = 
 SUMX(MMP_Dashboards_WMH_PBI, IF (MMP_Dashboards_WMH_PBI[Revenue_Center]IN {"FillRate","CancelRt","NoShowRt","ExamRt"},
DIVIDE ( 
Calculate(
SUM ( MMP_Dashboards_WMH_PBI[NewUnits] ), MMP_Dashboards_WMH_PBI[Revenue_Center] IN {"FillRate","CancelRt","NoShowRt","ExamRt"}
),

COUNTROWS ( VALUES ( MMP_Dashboards_WMH_PBI[Provider_Finance] )) 
),MMP_Dashboards_WMH_PBI[NewUnits]
))
```